# How to convert only my date to UTC dateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

I have a date picker on my website. It returns a string like this: `9/27/2015`
Ultimately, I need to have this format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`

The `Y-m-d` is no problem. Since I am not asking for the time, I'm not sure how to just get the current time and pass it along with the date that was chosen.

Something like...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$myDate = '9/27/2015 H:i:s'
```

This is as close as I have gotten & I realize it's because I'm just not doing it right.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('9/27/2015'));  // 2015-09-27 00:00:00
```

Which is fine, I don't necessarily *need* the time, but it would be great to just grab the current time and send that along. That way if in the future, I want to sort by date *and* time I can.

```
2015-09-27 10:21:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$onlyDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('9/27/2015'));
$onlyTime = date('H:i:s');
```

$date = $onlyDate.' '.$onlyTime;

get your date and current time.

Comment: Thank you so much - so obvious now that I see it.